# Не корректно работает localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Подскажите, почему некорректно работает localStorage в Safari и iOS.
Есть две страницы.
На первой вот этот код.

```
<button name="writead" id="anxx" class="j-submit-reportad">Загрузить</button>

var a = document.getElementById('anxx');
a.onclick = function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
localStorage.setItem('click1', 'div[data-filter=".jaluzi-vertical"]');

window.location.href = 'http://l-c.by/price';
}
```

Что он делает: записывает значение в localStorage и переходит на вторую страницу.
Вторая страница код:
Записывает после загрузки страницы в переменную id click1 и далее кликает $(id).click().

```
$(window).load(function() {
var  id = localStorage.getItem('click1');
$(id).click();
});
```

Работает корректно везде, кроме Mac и iOS, почему так, может есть другой способ, более кроссбраузерный ?

Comment: Я чёт не понял, почему у вас в одном коде `localStorage`, а в другом `sessionStorage`?

Comment: Просто не заметил,и там и там localStorage должен быть, просто пробовал и с sessionStorage, тоже самое. Может быть есть какие мысли ?

Comment: А есди передавать id GET-параметром или через хэш?

Comment: А это как ? :)(newbie)

Comment: А может использовать куки ?